# Bulk upload Excel to SQL Azure daily

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

I have a requirement to bulk upload data from a excel file to an Azure SQL table on a daily basis. I did some research and found that we could create a VM install full SQL and use SSIS package to do this. 
Is there any other reliable way to go about this? The excel may contain up to 10,000 rows. 
I have also read we could upload file to a blob storage and read from there but found it's not very robust approach.

Can anyone suggest if this is feasible approach-

- Place excel file in Azure Website accessed via FTP
- Azure Timer job using SQL Bulk copy code to update the SQL table

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure Data Factory - check out the [documentation here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/).  Place your files in Azure Data Lake and the ADF will process them.